# DNA of English language

Tags: history

Many Indian languages including Hindi(the language most spoken in India) owe their origin to Sanskrit.Similarly,is there any language which predated English and owes its origin?

Comment: The big words come from Latin.

Comment: Same place https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages

Comment: English is "descended" from a dozen different languages.  Major influences are (old) German, Norse, French, and Latin.  Being geographically isolated, the land would be "colonized" by relatively large groups with differing language backgrounds (eg, the Norse colonized much of Scotland), then those groups would slowly merge with other groups.

Answer (score 1):

English is classified as a [West Germanic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Germanic_languages) and descended from the languages of tribes in northern Germany and southern Denmark around the 5th century AD. However, it borrows a lot from Latin, French, Spanish, and other languages.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you put enough emphasis on "a lot."

Comment: And since America was the Great Melting Pot, AmE adopted many words from Native Americans, Eastern Europeans, etc. But not as many as the Romance languages that were adopted hundreds of years ago in England.